# Product of 2 digit numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ be distinct digits such that product of the two digit numbers $ab$ and $cb$ is of the form $ddd$ find all possible values of $a+b+c+d$.

I am not at all able to understand what should be the general approach. Just stuck. Some necessary hints might do the needful for me. If after the hints I am still not able to reach a conclusion then please guide me to the initial steps of the problem .

Comment: As a first step, its worth noting that you have $(10a+b)(10c+b) = 100ac+10ab+10cb+b^2 = 111d$. Can you think of any restrictions on the values of $a$ and $c$?

Comment: Yeah you are right @Brian, but can you please tell me how it is going to help, I am feeling that this can be done somehow. Little bit of insight.

Comment: @Brian I am not able to think, can I get some limitation on b and d after finding some restriction on a and c

Comment: Oh then I guess we need to make the RHS a perfect square for some suitable value of d and accordingly find b?

Comment: Hint: Since $111 = 3\times 37$ and $37$ is a prime, one of $ab$ or $cb$ needs to be divisible by $37$. There are not that many 2 digits integers that are divisible by $37$....

Comment: My mistake, $a\cdot c < 10$ is the condition, I interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Please check my approach and please say whether I am thinking in right direction or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(10a+b)(10c+b)=111d=3\cdot 37d$. And $37$ is prime, so it must divide one of the factors on the left-hand side, which we may suppose to be $10a+b$. Therefore $10a+b=37$ or $74$.

Each of these two possibilities gives you a different value of $d=b^2\bmod 10$, and you can check for possible values of $c$ by hand.

Comment: So from these conditions I am getting (10c+b)=3d and (10c+b)=3d/2 on putting 10a+b equal to 37 and 74 respectively

Comment: @TheLearner: Correct. One of these gives a valid value for $c$.

Comment: why we are doing d=b^2(mod10) I am missing some slight information here I guess

Comment: @TheLearner: Just do the arithmetic! Try a couple of examples if you don't see it.

Comment: Ok let me try I think it can be done now

Comment: I think the acceptable value I get for c should be from the second equation that is (10c+b)=3d/2. Am I correct?

Comment: Because that is the one which satisfies d=b^2(mod10)

Comment: Write down your values for $a,b,c,$ and $d$, and check whether $ab\times cb=ddd$...

Comment: I have written a different answer please check it once and please say whether this is right

Comment: I have written down the values of a b c d and it is working

Answer (score 0):

If I concentrate on units. $B^2$ should end with D. D≠B
as digits are distinct

$0^2=0;1^2=1;2^2=4;3^2=9;4^2=∗6;5^2=∗5;6^2=∗6;7^2=∗9$

$8^2=∗4;9^2=∗1$

Possible values of $D$ is $1,4,6 or 9$

$111=3∗37$

$444=2∗2∗3∗37$

$666=2∗3∗3∗37$

$999=3∗3∗3∗37=27∗37$

Only one possibility is seen $H=$ $27*37=999$
So $a+b+c+d=21$

Comment: This approach is valid but you need some justification why you can rule out $444$ and $666$ (the case for $111$ is obvious)